# Watcher to running array of threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading, loops

I have hash structure like `['a'=> false`, `'b' => false`, `'c' => false`, ......]. 
My conditions are:

- I am using multi-threading for each element and running some piece of code for making 'false' to true based on certain condition.
- This loop will continue till all element's value become 'true' or certain 'timeout'.
- I want a watcher which should collect those keys on each loop whose values become 'true' as i am running another code for these 'true' valued elements.

***However, the code i am writing doesn't have ruby-ism. It feels like writing java code.
Please help me for the ruby-ism approach.***

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to show the differences between two hashes extracted from active_support.

```
# from https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/diff.rb
def hash_diff(h1, h2)
  h1.dup.delete_if { |k, v| h2[k] == v }.merge!(h2.dup.delete_if { |k, v| h1.has_key?(k) })
end
```

Now you this is how you can use to detect differences between each iteration of your loop:

```
previous ||= my_hash
diff = hash_diff(my_hash, previous)
puts "Difference: #{diff.inspect}" unless diff.keys.empty?
previous = my_hash
```

Note that you may have to use mutexes for this code to avoid race conditions and other nasty errors.